# Powershell Get all Optical Drive Letters

Tags: windows, powershell, operating-system, disk

I am trying to get all drive letters of a Windows system with Powershell, but I cannot figure it out. 
Any Ideas?

I have tried to use `Get-Volume`, but it has no parameter for `-ByDriveType` or `-ByType` or `-Type` or anything.

Comment: This may be useful: http://superuser.com/questions/787613/viewing-all-accessible-drives-in-powershell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only want the optical drives (as mentioned in your title), use this:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk | ?{ $_.DriveType -eq 5} | select DeviceID
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead:

```
gdr -PSProvider 'FileSystem'
```

`gdr` is an alias for `Get-PSDrive`

Comment: This will return more than just optical drives.